# Fastify multipart/form-data error: "body must be object"

Tags: typescript, multer, multipart, form-data, fastify

I'm using fastify-multer and JSON Schema to submit multipart form data that may include a file. No matter what I do, Fastify keeps giving me a bad response error:

```json
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "body must be object"
}
```

Here is my `index.ts`:

```
const server = fastify();
server.register(require("@fastify/cors"));
server.register(multer.contentParser).after(() => {
    if (!isProdEnv) {
        server.register(require("@fastify/swagger"), {
            /* ... */
        });
    }
    server.register(require("@fastify/auth")).after(() => {
        server.decorate("authenticateRequest", authenticateRequest);
        server.decorate("requireAuthentication", requireAuthentication);
        server.addHook("preHandler", server.auth([server.authenticateRequest]));
        server.register(indexRouter);
        server.register(authRouter, { prefix: "/auth" });
        server.register(usersRouter, { prefix: "/users" });
        server.register(listsRouter, { prefix: "/lists" });
        server.register(postsRouter, { prefix: "/posts" });
        server.register(searchRouter, { prefix: "/search" });
        server.register(settingsRouter, { prefix: "/settings" });
    });
});
server.setErrorHandler((err, req, res) => {
    req.log.error(err.toString());
    res.status(500).send(err);
});
```

And the `/posts/create` endpoint:

```
const postsRouter = (server: FastifyInstance, options: FastifyPluginOptions, next: HookHandlerDoneFunction) => {
    server.post(
        "/create",
        {
            schema: {
                consumes: ["multipart/form-data"],
                body: {
                    content: {
                        type: "string"
                    },
                    media: {
                        type: "string",
                        format: "binary"
                    },
                    "media-description": {
                        type: "string"
                    }
                }
            },
            preHandler: [server.auth([server.requireAuthentication]), uploadMediaFileToCloud]
        },
        postsController.createPost
    );
    next();
};

export default postsRouter;
```

Request CURL:

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://localhost:3072/posts/create' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJoYW5kbGUiOiJ1bGtrYSIsInVzZXJJZCI6IjYyNGQ5NmY4NzFhOTI2OGY2YzNjZWExZCIsImlhdCI6MTY1NzEwNTg5NCwiZXhwIjoxNjU3NDA1ODk0fQ.A5WO3M-NhDYGWkILQLVCPfv-Ve-e_Dlm1UYD2vj5UrQ' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F 'content=Test.' \
  -F 'media=@flame-wolf.png;type=image/png' \
  -F 'media-description=' \
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: could you add the client's request?  A curl would be perfect

Comment: Moreover I don't see the https://github.com/fastify/fastify-multipart registration

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon I have added CURL. Also, is `fastify-multipart` required for `fastify-multer` to work? It's never mentioned anywhere in the documentation!

Comment: No, but your question doesn't not contain it neither

Comment: `fastify-multer` is imported in the beginning of `index.ts`. I skipped that part here, thinking the line `server.register(multer.contentParser)` implied it.

Comment: It is not compatible with fastify v4. Try to use the official fastify-multipart plugin instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT 2: Apparently, there is a really easy solution for this: Use multer in the `preValidation` hook instead of `preHandler`. So, a piece of working code will look like this:

```
server.register(multer.contentParser).after(() => {
    server.register(
        (instance: FastifyInstance, options: FastifyPluginOptions, next: HookHandlerDoneFunction) => {
            instance.post(
                "/create",
                {
                    schema: {
                        consumes: ["multipart/form-data"],
                        body: {
                            type: "object",
                            properties: {
                                content: {
                                    type: "string"
                                },
                                media: {
                                    type: "string",
                                    format: "binary"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    preValidation: multer({
                        limits: {
                            fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5
                        },
                        storage: multer.memoryStorage()
                    }).single("media")
                },
                (request: FastifyRequest, reply: FastifyReply) => {
                    const content = (request.body as any).content as string;
                    const file = (request as any).file as File;
                    if (file) {
                        delete file.buffer;
                    }
                    reply.send({
                        content,
                        file: JSON.stringify(file) || "No file selected"
                    });
                }
            );
            next();
        },
        { prefix: "/posts" }
    );
});
```

---

EDIT: After I posted the answer below, I was able to find a solution for this. Updating my answer for anyone else who might encounter the same issue.

First, I switched to `@fastify/multipart` from `fastify-multer`. Then I removed the `type` property from the `media` field.

```
media: {
    format: "binary"
}
```

After this, I added the option`{ addToBody: true }` when registering `@fastify/multipart`.

```
import fastifyMultipart from "@fastify/multipart";

server.register(fastifyMultipart, { addToBody: true }).after(() => { ... });
```

After these changes, the field `media` became available in `request.body`.

---

*OLD ANSWER:*

Seems like these days I have to answer my own questions here. Anyway, I figured out what's happening. Fastify's built-in schema validation doesn't play well with `multipart/form-data`. I played around with the schema specification to make sure that this is the case. So I removed schema validation from all routes. My use case here was porting an API from ExpressJS to Fastify, so I had a nice Swagger JSON spec generated using [express-oas-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-oas-generator) lying around. I used that to generate Swagger UI and everything worked fine. I hope Fastify gets its act together and sorts out this issue.

Comment: sensei @Mr.X . I am very grateful for your answers.

Comment: I created this multipart/form-data parser plugin to solve this issue without any workarounds. https://www.npmjs.com/package/formzilla